# How to calculate minimum distance in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, graph, multidimensional-array, adjacency-matrix

I have a matrix, the distance in matrix is calculated using euclidean distance.
After that, i have to search the minimum distance between object. But i have to keep the destination vertex as source vertex. I give the example.

```
P1      P2      P3      P4      
0       3,0014  1,1245  1,1000  
3,0014  0       3,0571  2,5374  
1,1245  3,0571  0       1,0651  
1,1000  2,5374  1,0651  0
```

The minimum distance based on object P1 is : (P1,P4: 1,1000), (P1,P3: 1,1245), (P1,P2: 3,0014)
But i have to display the trail in object P1, the trail should be: (P1, P4), (P4,P3), (P3,P2)
P1 is source vertex, and P4 is destination vertex, then P4 should be the source vertex and ect.
I have to write in java code
This is the method i try:

```
 public LinkedList<EdgeTest> getKruskalEdge(Double kDistance, int index) {
    PriorityQueue<EdgeTest> edge = new PriorityQueue<EdgeTest>();
    if (index == -1) {
        System.out.println("Kosong");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexList.length; i++) {

            if (adjMat[index][i] != -1 && adjMat[index][i] != 0) {
                if (adjMat[index][i] <= kDistance) {




                    edge.add(new EdgeTest(vertexList[index].toString(),
                            vertexList[i].toString(), adjMat[index][i]));


                }
            }


        }
        System.out.println("");
        while (!edge.isEmpty()) {

            insertEdge(edge.remove());

        }
    }
    return kruskalEdge;
}
```

Comment: How is your matrix mapped to `ArrayList`?

Comment: i have tried but the result is : P1, P4= 1.0999999999999999
P1, P3= 1.1244554237496476
P1, P2= 1.309809146402635.. it should be P1,P4; P4,P3; P3,P2